# why images created with GD in php has a low quality?

Tags: php, gd

i am creating a thumbnail from my pictures but the result have a low quality! and colors are mixed. what can i do for this?

part of my code:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcImage);
imagecopyresized($thumb,$source,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($thumb,$desImage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace imagecopyresized with imagecopyresampled to make the resizing better.

Then you can change the third argument to imagejpeg to change the quality of the save. The default is 75 and max is 100.

Comment: Can you make this a higher quality answer? Perhaps the exact item that needs changed. :-)

Comment: thanks the result is better :) , is it possible to control the output quality?      and what is the difference betwin them?!

Comment: Third argument to imagejpeg decides quality. The default is 75. So make it higher if you want better quality.

Comment: jpeg images lose quality when you save it, it's possible the quality lose is to due jpeg being a lossy file format.